# How to get lastest data from redis at real time?

Tags: redis, lettuce

I want to implement real-time applications with Redis.

There are data that are pushed in real time on Redis, like the source code below that used lettuce library.

```
RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create(uri);
StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = redisClient.connect() 

RedisStringAsyncCommands<String, String> asyncCommands = connection.async();
List<RedisFuture<?>> futures = Lists.newArrayList(); 

while(true) {
    futures.add(asyncCommands.set("key", "value"));
}
```

If I want to check the data at client in real time, how can I implement it?

At first time, I used pub/sub way, but the pub/sub method could not get the stored data.
 It was just publish data - channel - subscribe data in real time.

For example, Kafka can continuously get data through the consumer, like that.

```
while(true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
        logger.info("offset = {}, value = {}", record.offset(), record.value());
    }
}
```

Are there some ways?

Comment: You can try [Redis Stream[(https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro)

Comment: along with streams you can also try [redis-notification](https://redis.io/topics/notifications)

Comment: Thx, I will try to.